# Validar que exista valor de un select

Tags: php

Tengo una clase que va a buscar el valor máximo de una columna según cierta condición.
Si se encuentra algún registro que cumple con la condición, el valor de la variable `$row` se va a incrementar en 1.

Si no existe ningún registro que cumpla con la condición, a la variable `$row` se le asigna el valor de 1.

Este es el código:

```
public function numerar($per, $lib) {
    try {
            $bd = new ConDB();
            $sql = "SELECT MAX(asiento) FROM TABLA WHERE per = :per AND lib = :lib";
            $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':per', $per, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':lib', $lib, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ( $stmt->fetchColumn() !== NULL) {
                $row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
                $row++;
            } else {
                $row = 1;
            }
            echo $row;
```

Pero no incrementa en 1 cuando cumple la condición, no muestra nada.
Los campos `per` y `lib` son *integer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Los métodos *`fetch`*  mueven el puntero**. Por tanto aquí: `$row = $stmt->fetchColumn();` ya no habrá nada, porque más arriba ya moviste el puntero: `if ( $stmt->fetchColumn() !== NULL) {`, y, si la consulta tuviera más de una fila, el puntero, cuando asignas `$row`, estaría en la segunda fila. Sí, sí, porque cada vez que aplicas `fetch` el puntero se mueve. Es por eso por lo que los `fetch` se vacían en bucles (salvo  `fetchAll`, que vacía todo el puntero de golpe).

Además, tu código se puede simplificar con un ternario:

```
$row=$stmt->fetchColumn();
$row = ($row) ? $row++ : 1;
echo $row;
```

Para información, veamos lo que ocurre con tu código actual:

```
/*
    La llamada $stmt->fetchColumn() mueve el puntero a la primera fila
    O devuelve false si no hay filas ...
*/
if ( $stmt->fetchColumn() !== NULL) { #Se mueve una fila
    /*
       La siguiente llamada a fetchColumn()
       mueve el puntero a la siguiente fila, si la hubiera
       Y si no la hay, la llamada retornará false
       Dado que tu consulta devuelve una sola fila
       $row se está quedando con false
       Si hubiera más filas, 
       aquí $row adquirirá el valor de la siguiente fila
    */
    $row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    $row++;
} else {
    $row = 1;
}
/*
   Aquí $row es false cuando hay datos
   Y si no hay datos es igual a 1
   Dado que los false no se ven en pantalla,
   verifícalo con var_dump
*/
var_dump($row);
```

Comment: Pero si la sentencia tiene `SELECT MAX(asiento)`, solamente se obtendrá una fila como resultado en cualquier caso. Cierto?

Comment: @Puntay claro, por eso, como expliqué en la respuesta, en el primer `fetchColumn()`  (el del `if`) ya sacas el único resultado que trae la consulta, y en el segundo `fetchColumn` ya no harbrá nada.